# Change color of the shadow in background

Tags: ios, swift, background-color, shadow

I`ve a App like the iOS 10 Maps-App or maybe like the Home-Screen with Control Center. For example take a look at the Picture. If you open the Control Center the shadow of the background changes to black & transparent. How can i access this layer or subview and change the color from this shadow to another in my App. Maybe to red or white?

[image]

**EDIT:**

Maybe directly with the Framework.
https://github.com/iosphere/ISHPullUp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes open your eyes and you will find what you want.  If you using the same Framework there is one variable you can change. In the sample of the Framework you can got to the "BottomVC" and add the following line to your `viewDidLoad()`.

```
weak var pullUpController: ISHPullUpViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTapGesture))
       topView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
       handleView.arrowSize = CGSize(width: 1 , height: 2)

      //This line change the default 40% black to a 70% white.
      pullUpController.dimmingColor = UIColor.white().withAlphaComponent(0.7)

}
```

The "Shadow" is just a normal View. [Here](https://github.com/iosphere/ISHPullUp/blob/master/ISHPullUp/ISHPullUpViewController.m) you can see how the author has implemented this.

Comment: Side note: The Framework needed xCode 8 and Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UIVisualEffectView** like this:
**Obj-C:**

```
UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];//SELECT STYLE OF YOUR CHOICE
    UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;//view Will be YOUR_VIEW
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [self.view addSubview:blurEffectView];//This add Blur view to your view
```

**Swift:**

```
 let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Comment: If i make it with a blur i think i need to add this effect in a other ViewController. I'm not sure what happens if i open View like the Control Center but in my mind it will move the View behind the Control Center backward, add a layer or view and open the "Control Center"- View. So in my opinion it must be possible to access this "View" and modify it.

Comment: You will have to add blur view on the view controller which you want to show as blur. When you will show your view the blur view should be added to the background view controller. Do you want to access background view also when you will show your new view over it?

Comment: @VishalSonawane Side note: when copying code you want to paste in SO, do not select [like this](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOwSX5XOhcVDc4wd3J_tulhjnrUIAcdcCwo) but [like this](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOypRynS_EZPGrxkraOuBOMddAU_ArXhNJs). This way it respects indentation when pasting. :)

Comment: Something like that. I got 3 View Controller. "MainVC", "ContentVC", "BottomVC". If i have to use a blur i need to add it to over the "MainVC" or "ContentVC" at the moment i open the "BottomVC".